# Using generics in kotlin that support multiplication

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following code and trying to make it generic so it will accept Int, Float, Long, Double.

I think the issue is that Number doesn't have any add, subtract, multiple, etc. Just wondering what I can do?

```
private fun <T: Number> productNumbers(listOfNumbers: List<T>, ignoreIndex: Int): T {
    val totalProduct = listOfNumbers.foldIndexed(1 as T) { index,  acc, number ->
        if(index != ignoreIndex) {
            acc * number
        }
        else {
            acc
        }
    }

    return totalProduct
}
```

Comment: There is not a good way to do generics over different kinds of numbers.  Don't try.

Comment: It might help to think of `Number` _not_ as a number in itself, but as merely ‘something that can be _converted_ to any primitive numeric type’ (as those are the only methods it has, apart from a couple of related extensions).  While there are many situations in which a general numeric supertype would be handy, this isn't it, unfortunately.  (And there's no good way to add one.)  In practice, you can usually cover most of what you need by implementing for `long` and/or `double` (adding in the other primitive types and/or `BigInteger`/`BigDecimal` if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the issue with your generic function is that the Number type in Kotlin doesn't directly support arithmetic operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. This is because Number is a common supertype for numeric types (Int, Float, Long, Double, etc.), each of which implements these operations differently.

To create a generic function for arithmetic operations in Kotlin, you typically need to use some form of conditional logic or type checks to handle each specific numeric type. However, this approach can become verbose and complex, especially for more advanced operations.

In your specific case, a better approach would be to use a higher-order function that accepts an operation to apply to the numbers. This way, you can pass the specific operation (like multiplication) as a lambda function. Here's how you can modify your productNumbers function:

```
private fun <T: Number> productNumbers(
listOfNumbers: List<T>,
ignoreIndex: Int,
operation: (T, T) -> T
): T {
    val totalProduct = listOfNumbers.foldIndexed(1.toNumberType(listOfNumbers.first())) { index, acc, number ->
        if (index != ignoreIndex) {
            operation(acc, number)
        } else {
            acc
        }
    }

return totalProduct
}

// Helper extension function to convert Int to the same type as the first number in the list
private fun <T: Number> Int.toNumberType(firstNumber: T): T {
    return when(firstNumber) {
        is Int -> this as T
        is Long -> toLong() as T
        is Float -> toFloat() as T
        is Double -> toDouble() as T
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported number type")
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val product = productNumbers(numbers, 2) { a, b -> a * b }
println(product)
```

Comment: Is it not counterintuitive for the result of multiplying numbers together to depend so strongly on their order?  The standard numeric promotions in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6), C, etc. take into account the type of _all_ the operands (usually taking the ‘largest’ type, where that makes sense).

Comment: Can you not avoid the type enumeration in `Int.toNumberType` with: `private fun <T: Number> Int.inferType(number: T): T = this as T
`  ?